# "What does this mean: key=lambda x: x[-1] ?"

Tags: python, sorting, lambda, key

I know that `a.sort(key=lambda x: x[1])` means it sorts with respect to second element.
But `x[-1]`??
Shouldn't there be only two configurations `x[0]` and `x[1]`?
Or am I missing something obvious?
Lets consider `a = [(10, 4), (3, 5), (7, 1)]`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Python has the ability to index from the `end` of a list. Hence, `x[-1]` refers to the last element, `x[-2]` refers to the second to last element, etc.

```
a.sort(key=lambda x: x[-1])
```

will sort `a` by the last element.

```
>>> a = [(10, 4), (3, 5), (7, 1)]

>>> a.sort(key=lambda x: x[-1])
[(7, 1), (10, 4), (3, 5)]
```

Comment: So what will happen if I put `a.sort(key=lambda x: x[-1] * x[-2])`?
What does it multiply?

Comment: @KarthikReddy It will sort by the quantities that are obtained by multiplying the `last element` by the `second to the last element` (`second` by the `first` in the case of size 2 tuples)

Answer (score 0):

You are sorting by the last element of every tuple (ie, by 4, 5, 1 instead of by 10, 3, 7, resp.)